# Why does my function only work when only using ternary operators instead of regular if/else statements?

Tags: typescript

Take the following function:

```
getContent(config?: DataResourceConfig, forceResponse?: boolean, errorCode?: number): Observable<any> {
        if (config.format) {
            config.format = config.format.toUpperCase();

            if (config.format === FORMAT.GraphQL) {
                return this.http.post<any>(this.graphQLEndpoint, config.query);
            } else {
                return this.http.get<Faq>(this.endpoint);
            }
        } else {
            if (forceResponse === undefined) {

                return this.http.get<Faq>(this.endpoint);
            } else {
                const faq = FAQS_MOCK;
                const error = mockError(errorCode, this.endpoint);
                return forceResponse ? of(faq) : throwError(error);
            }
        }

    }
```

if i use it locally in my Angular application it works as expected, but when I move it into an external library it doesn't. However, when I refactor it to use ternary operators like so

```
getContent(config?: DataResourceConfig, forceResponse?: boolean, errorCode?: number): Observable<any> {
       return config.format
           ? config.format === FORMAT.GraphQL
               ? this.http.post<any>(config.url, config.query)
               :  this.http.get<Faq>(config.url)
           : forceResponse === undefined
               ? this.http.get<Faq>(config.url)
               : forceResponse
                   ? of(FAQS_MOCK)
                   : throwError(mockError(errorCode, config.url));
   }
```

It works as expected again. Clearly there is some compiling error that is happening when it's written the first way. I'm wondering why does this work when I switch to ternary operators?

Also, I should add I tried modifying the function so that it the return value is saved to a variable and returned at the top level and still it didn't work.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Also there are quite some differences apart from the ternary / if thing, e.g. `this.graphQLEndpoint` being replaced with `config.url`, the call to `mockError` even if `throwError` is not called.

Comment: I would stick with `if ... else ...` - as the code is at least readable

Comment: Agree with Jonas: the two are quite  different. Only one has `toUpperCase`; only one uses `this.endpoint`; only one uses `config.url`; only one uses `this.graphQLEndpoint`; one may call `mockError` when the other would not (when `forceResponse` is truthy); ...

Comment: Your code does not appear to be Javascript. Edited the tag.

Comment: @JonasWilms it won't proceed past config.format in the first if statement even though what I'm passing is valid. I was only able to get the first if statement in the else to return. Everything else just failed silently.

Comment: @JonasWilms When I took that code and called into within my component. Everything worked as expected, hence why I'm fairly confident it's a compiling issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your if/else block is different from the ternary block, as others have stated in the comments above. The if/else block equivalent of the ternary block is this:

```ts
    getContent(config?: DataResourceConfig, forceResponse?: boolean, errorCode?: number): Observable<any> {
      if (config.format) {
        if (config.format === FORMAT.GraphQL) {
          return this.http.post<any>(config.url, config.query);
        } else {
          return this.http.get<Faq>(config.url);
        }
      } else {
        if (forceResponse === undefined) {
          return this.http.get<Faq>(config.url);
        } else if (forceResponse) {
          return of(FAQS_MOCK);
        } else {
          return throwError(mockError(errorCode, config.url));
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: So it seems my ternary operator has a else if? That doesn't explain why I couldn't get the code to execute beyond the first if statement even if I had 'config.format'

Comment: The fact that the if/else block you pasted above is different in logic from the ternary block could explain your error. You use config.url in the ternary block but this.endpoint in the if/else block